# Shorthand for multiple or operator to check if different variables are an empty string

Tags: javascript

Is there a shorthand for the following?

`startsWith !== '' || contains !== '' || endsWith !== ''`

I am looking for something more clean but not the overkill

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that they are variables, you could create an array from `startsWith`, `contains` and `endsWith` and then check the array contains an empty string like below:

```
const array = [startsWith, contains, endsWith];

if (!array.includes('')) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Could also use `.filter(Boolean)` if you want a list of the values that arent empty strings

Comment: True, but the conditions we start with are explicitly a "not equal to an empty string", rather than a truthy check